# Difference between lastBaselineToBottomHeight and paddingBottom

Tags: android, android-layout, padding

For an `EditText`, what is difference between:

```
android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight
```

and

```
android:padddingBottom
```

Layout preview shows that `android:lastBaselineToBottomHeight` adds gap between text and line of `EditText` whereas in this website, it is mentioned at many places that `android:paddingBottom` does that job.

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/whats-new-for-text-in-android-p.html